# hadoop cluster on virtual machines

Tags: hadoop

I have to setup a cluster, on my computer using 5 virtual machines with hadoop. The configuration requires a port number. Can someone enlighten me on this.I am a beginner in it

Answer (score 3):

If your primary objective is to learn Hadoop then it does not matter you learn it on Windows or Linux, because everything is exactly same on both platforms. I have extensively used Hadoop on both platform and found all the commands and processing are identical on Windows and Linux. So here are my suggestions:

1. Download VMware VMPlayer on your Windows/Linux Machine
2. Download CDH Virtual Machine for VMware

   https://ccp.cloudera.com/display/SUPPORT/Downloads

Access virtual machine in your Windows/Linux box and follow the tutorials exactly they are on Linux.

Same info is shared here:

[Hadoop on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10310736/hadoop-on-windows/10310828#10310828)

Comment: I have to configure the hadoop. The nodes need a port number, so can you help me regarding that what port number to give

Comment: The default Hadoop is set to run with port 50030 and 50070 so you don't need to play with any Port setting. Either you don't examplain what your actual requirements are or you dont know what you are doing. The best option is to download the cloudera VM and then learn how it works and then try to run your own cluster.

Answer (score 0):

Its upto you to choose the port. Normally people use the default ports provided by hadoop. For the default ports, see [this](http://www.cloudera.com/blog/2009/08/hadoop-default-ports-quick-reference/). There will be absolutely no harm if you use those ports (unless you have something else running on any of those ports).