# Installing Hive on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop, hive

I want to install Hive on my Ubuntu.I read [this](http://www.hackido.com/2010/05/install-hadoop-and-hive-on-ubuntu-lucid.html) Article,that help me so much.I did all of steps except step 4.I didn't understand exactly what should in this step do.

could you please explain me this step in detail ?

Comment: The link is broken.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does step #3 went without hitch? Upto step 3 you are downloading the binaries from SVN to your machine and step 4 is setting the binaries with your Hadoop Environment.

Step 4  suggests you the following:

export PATH=$PATH:/usr/src/hive/build/dist/bin/

-> Means you are adding directory /usr/src/hive/build/dist/bin/ in your PATH environment. You must have installed hive in this folder -> /usr/src/hive/build/dist/bin/ so adding this folder (actually Hive Binaries) in your path will let you run Hive in your machine.

export PATH=$PATH:/usr/src/hive/build/dist/lib/

-> Means you are adding directory /usr/src/hive/build/dist/lib/ in your PATH environment. When you have installed Hive on your machine, Hive related libraries are located in this folder > /usr/src/hive/build/dist/lib/ so adding this directory to your PATH, will help Hive to run successfully.

export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/hadoop/bin

-> If you already have Hadoop running in your machine, this should already set otherwise this command is just setting Hadoop Binary folder in your machine path.

If you dont know what is PATH, just look for "PATH in Linux" at internet.

Comment: Thank you for your answer .I have installed my Hive in this Path**Downloads/hive/** then I should change export command path.did I get correctly?

Comment: Are you sure? I don't think you have installed instead i think you have just download it. Installation is mostly done at /usr/* location so i am not sure. IF u just try to find hive binary at /downloads/hive/ and if found, you sure can add this folder as /downloads/hive/build/dist/bin in your path.

Comment: Thank you Avkash :) to be honest I changed th PATH commands and change it to /home/babak/Downloads/hive/build/dist/bin .and then I get an java error like this**/home/babak/Downloads/hadoop/bin/../bin hadoop: row 258:/usr/lib/j2sdk1.5-sun/bin/java: file or Folder not found**    Hive binary? what is it?

Comment: It seems your path are not correct.. you really need to understand that all the binaries (libs & bin) must be in path to get working..

Comment: that means I should not change the Path ?

Comment: i am not able to understand how did u install. If you have installed hive @ /home/babak/Downloads/hive/build/dist/bin and here /home/babak/Downloads/hive/build/dist/lib you just need to EXPORT  these two folder in path, thats it.

Comment: I'm confused in this platform. and I dont know exactly what I did and what should I do.Is it Possible to install hive and [hadoop on windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10857605/is-it-posible-to-install-hive-and-haddop-on-windows)?

Comment: Do one this follow my solution to download VM and run on Windows http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10559396/hadoop-cluster-on-virtual-machines/10559545#10559545. Most of these VM have Hive on it or u can install Hive very easily on it.

Answer (score 5):

Step 1 : Download and Extract Hadoop

Step 2 : Set JAVA_HOME path to conf/hadoop-env.sh  //This step is to set java path for hadoop

Step 3 : conf/core-site.xml:

```
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>fs.default.name</name>  //Place your home folder here for using hadoop 
    <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

Step 4 : conf/hdfs-site.xml:

```
<configuration>          //This setting for the number of replications of the file or you can add data node for the save the file
  <property>
    <name>dfs.replication</name>
    <value>1</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

Step 5 : conf/mapred-site.xml:

```
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>mapred.job.tracker</name>
    <value>localhost:9001</value>        // add your master host in the place of localhost here
  </property>
</configuration>
```

Step 6 : Login SSH localhost and Format a new distributed-filesystem

```
bin/hadoop namenode -format
```

Step 7 : Start the hadoop daemons:

```
bin/start-all.sh
```

Step 8 : Check the NameNode & JobTracker below port

```
http://localhost:50070/       //master
http://localhost:50030/       //slave
```

// Its is also better to try the ssh for check your working nodes

Step 9 : Download and Extract Hive

Step 10 : Set below Env variables.

```
export HADOOP_HOME=<hadoop-install-dir>
export HIVE_HOME=<hive-install-dir>
export PATH=$HIVE_HOME/bin:$PATH
$HIVE_HOME/bin/hive
```

Answer (score 0):

[This PPA](https://launchpad.net/~hadoop-ubuntu/+archive/stable) makes it pretty easy to install Hive on Ubuntu.