# Is it posible to install Hive and Hadoop on Windows?

Tags: windows, hadoop, hive

I want to know if I can install Hive on windows? If yes how can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of now the Microsoft provided "Hadoop on Windows" is not available to not available to general consumption and there is no public information about its general availability.

If you see my blog below you will see that I have had chance to use the binaries in past but then most of the focus is on "[Hadoop on Azure](https://www.hadooponazure.com/)" now which is in limited CTP release 2:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/avkashchauhan/archive/2012/01/28/creating-your-own-hadoop-cluster-on-windows-azure-by-using-your-own-windows-azure-subscription-account.aspx

I would say that there are developers who have written some articles or solution on having Hadoop and other components running on Windows using Cigwin which you can try however there is nothing very robust and stable I really know. If you really want to give a try I would personally suggest downloading [Cloudera Hadoop VM](https://ccp.cloudera.com/display/SUPPORT/Cloudera%27s+Hadoop+Demo+VM) on your Windows Box and give a try using any Virtual Machine player application.

Answer (score 0):

- http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r1.0.3/single_node_setup.html

You need to install cygwin.

*Would* I? No; I'd run the Cloudera VMs and not try to deal with all the possible issues.

Comment: Is ther a way to install cloudera on windows 7?

Comment: @iav-babak No clue; I haven't run any VMs on Win7. I would assume so.

Answer (score 0):

Coming real-soon-now is the Hadoop for Windows Server program formerly known as Isotope.

- [Getting Started with Hadoop For Windows Server](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/6218.getting-started-with-hadoop-based-services-for-windows-en-us.aspx)

Performance is way better than using Cygwin equivalent install - all the file I/O is done natively instead.  Comes with Pig and Hive thrown into the bag too, and has an Azure equivalent install package as well - check it out.

Comment: It seem that it is only for windows server.Can I use It on Windows 7?

Comment: Never tried, but I suspect yes.  It will be a) unsupported b) you may need to manually unpack the MSI to install it.  (suspect there is an OS check right up front in the MSI)